# storing user input to a variable as user is typing it in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to store user input as the user is typing it into a variable in javascript. I know how to do it using a button but I want it to be real time so as the user is typing something the variable is changing with user input. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `onkeyup` to do that. Whenever a key is pressed a function will be called and in that function a variable will always have the value of the input box as the user types

```js
function a()
{
var d=document.getElementById("a").value
console.log(d)
}
```

```html
<input id="a" onkeyup="a()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 cents

```
let storedValue = '';

//Get input field from DOM.
let inputField = document.querySelector('inputField');

//Attach keyup/keydown event listener to the input
inputField.addEventListener('keyup',function()
{
    storedValue = inputField.value;
});
```